# Let $f:E \to \Bbb R$ be measurable. Let $B \in \operatorname{Bor}(\Bbb R)$ be a Borel set. Show that $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $E$ be some measurable domain and $f:E \to \Bbb R$ a measurable map. Let $B \in \operatorname{Bor}(\Bbb R)$ be a Borel set. Show that $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.

I'm advised to define $\mathcal{A} = \{A \mid f^{-1}(A) \text{ measurable} \}$. Now $\mathcal{A}$ consists of sets whose preimage is measurable, and since $f$ is continuous these sets are open. This collection seems to form a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$, but I'm confused about the construction here as it seems that $\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing open sets, but that would mean that it's equal to $ \operatorname{Bor}(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Um, this is just the definition of measurability.

Comment: You might want to tell us what $E$ is.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $E$ is some measurable domain.

Comment: Don’t clarify in comments, edit the question.@RicoJello

Comment: You might wanna tell if $f$ is continuous or merely measurable. To say $f$ is continuous you want to put a topology on $E$. To say $\mathcal A$ is a sigma algebra on $\mathbb R$ you want $E = \mathbb R$. In any case $f$ constant yields $\mathcal A = \{ \emptyset, E\}$ which is not the borrel sigma algebra on $\mathbb R$. Can you find an example of $f : \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous such that $\mathcal A$ is the borrel sigma algebra?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof will depend on your definition of "measurable function".

Let's say "measurable function" means $f^{-1}(G)$ is measurable for all open sets $G \subseteq \mathbb R$.

Then define $\mathcal{A} = \{A \subseteq \mathbb R \mid f^{-1}(A) \text{ measurable} \}$.  Show that $\mathcal{A}$ contains all open sets and that $\mathcal A$ is a sigma-algebra.  Conclude that $\mathcal A \supseteq \operatorname{Bor}(\Bbb R)$.

---

Note: you cannot prove $\mathcal A = \operatorname{Bor}(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: I've managed to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, but cannot convince myself that this collection contains all open sets in $\Bbb R$. You have the correct definition that I'm using for a measurable function.

Comment: Use your definition of "$f$ is a measurable function" to show $\mathcal A$ contains all open sets.  This should not be hard, it is following the definitions.

Comment: Let's see if I got it right. $\mathcal{A}$ is the collection of sets for which $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable. Now $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable if and only if $A$ is open implying that the sets $A$ must be the open sets in the target space which is $\Bbb R$ in this case?

Comment: Here's the problem. I don't think the statement "Now $f^{-1}(A)$ is measurable if and only if $A$ is open" is true?

Comment: No, your "if and only if" is not right.  Say "if".  Then the sets in $\mathcal{A}$ are at least the open sets in $\mathbb R$.  In fact, the sets in $\mathcal A$ could be more than the open sets.